# Button 3D-style Text padding

Tags: android, button, text, styles, padding

I have some buttons in my main screen. These are all designed by a buttonstyle xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"             android:drawable="@drawable/button_faq" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_faq_pushed" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_faq_pushed" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_faq" />
</selector>
```

To make it more 3D, I would like to put the Button-Text 4px down, if the button is pressed.

How can I implement this?

Comment: is "button_faq_pushed" an image or xml?

Answer (score 0):

try adding shape and play with padding values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_faq" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_faq_pushed" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape>
                 <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
            </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:="" android:drawable="@drawable/button_faq_pushed" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_faq"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: did you change 10dp values to your needs?